# Formatting a hard drive for just OS X using a PC?

Tags: macos, time-machine, format

I'm looking to format an external hard drive for use exclusively Mac OS X (for use with the time machine feature), but the Mac that I'm using is too slow to format the entire harddrive.

Considering I own a PC that's much faster than that, is there any way I could use Linux or Windows to format it for Mac OS X?

Comment: Why would the Mac be *too slow to format a hard drive*?

Comment: @slhck Because it's an iMac G4 (quite old). (Much like this: http://www.flickr.com/photos/larsa/3333151930/)

Comment: I thought the speed a harddrive is formatted at relied more upon the cabling/data transfer than the speed of the system...

Comment: @Nano8Blazex You're right, the ports on the iMac are USB 1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS X uses [HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS+) as the file format for external disks. Note that Apple only supplies read-only drivers for Windows, which means that there's no easy way to write.

However, there are a couple of commercial tools to format as HFS+ using Windows:

### [TransMac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm)

> TransMac for Windows can open Macintosh format disk drives, flash drives, CD/DVD/Blu-ray media, high density diskettes, dmg and sparseimage files. [...] **Format disks for use on Mac**

### [MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/products/macdrive)

> MacDrive™ 8 allows Windows users to open, edit and save files on Mac disks. [...] What if you need to format a Mac disk or create and delete partitions on a Mac drive? You can, using the powerful MacDrive Disk Manager.

Both offer free trials though.

That being said, I don't see why a Mac would be *too slow* to format a drive. Be on the safe side and just do it on the Mac, even if it takes a while longer.